# jUnit: How to determine level of code coverage?

Tags: junit, code-coverage

How can i determine what percentage of my methods (and code) are covered by jUnit tests? I am assuming there is a more sophisticated way then simply counting `... and 1 and 2 and ..`

I specifically wonder how will such counting be handled when single method is covered by 'n' tests.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I've used [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) very successfully to cover JUnit test runs.  And its free.

Comment: Not sure if this is the best answer. I have looked at EclEmma and it appear it is an eclipse plugin. I need to do this in a CI environment and EclEmma is not available as a gradle plugin.

Comment: EclEmma's underlying test library, [JaCoCo](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/), is available as a Maven plugin and I think can be used in a CI environment. I'm not sure if a Graddle plugin is available.

Answer (score 3):

[This presentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20150829061038/http://ibiblio.org/java/slides/albany/codecoverage/Measuring_JUnit_Code_Coverage.html) points to several tools you can use for the purpose.

> - Cenqua Clover $250-$2500 payware http://www.cenqua.com/clover/
> - Cobertura (GPL): http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/
> - Coverlipse Eclipse plug-in:
>     http://coverlipse.sourceforge.net/index.php
> - Jester: http://jester.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to go for [Cobertura](https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura) for code coverage. It gives detailed information and can give you line by line coverage as well as branch coverage.